# How to programmatically open a file from FileProvider Extension (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider-extension

Is there a way to programmatically open a file from FileProvider Extension?

My use case is that I have FileProviderUI-extension for macOS which shows a dialog with 'Open file' button. And I'd like when user clicks on 'Open file' button to open the relevant file.

However, when I execute:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(itemURL)
```

a Finder error is shown: *The application “MyAppAction (Finder)” does not have permission to open “My File.txt.”*

I guess this is related to FileProviderExtension being sandboxed, but is there a way to open FileProvider files programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

```
Task{
    guard let fileProviderFolderURL = try! await NSFileProviderManager(for: domain)?.getUserVisibleURL(for: .rootContainer) else{
        print("No CloudStorage URL found")
        return
    }

    fileProviderFolderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    let openResult = NSWorkspace.shared.open(fileProviderFolderURL)
    if !openResult {
        print("There was an error opening FileProvider Folder")
    }
    fileProviderFolderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}
```

Just fetch the FileProvider item with `getUserVisibleURL` and make sure `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` is invoked before accessing it.

Comment: But this seems to work only if user selected his Home folder for place where Bookmark Alias folder should be created. If it was created in ie Documents folder, then `NSWorkspace.shared.open(...)` will fail.